# how to display texboxes dynamically in android app development?

Tags: android

Hi I need to display the EditText boxes dynamically depending upon some number. I tried like this:

```
   et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    et3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    et3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    et4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    et4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    et5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    et5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    for(i=1;i<=wl;++i)
    {
    et+i.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

I am new to android app development. I knew there is something wrong in the for loop...could anyone fix it?? and also it would be appreciated if someone come up with some other method to disply the EditText box dynamically

Comment: Why don't you keep `et` variables in an array and loop over them?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do "et+i" in Java!

You can create ArrayList, then put to it et1, et2, et3... and then iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you were thinking about something more like this:

```
EditText[] ets = new EditText[5];
int i;
ets[0]=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
ets[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ets[1]=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
ets[1].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
...
ets[4]=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
ets[4].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
for(i=0;i<=4;++i)
{
  ets[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Then again, if you're using `findViewById`, you're not likely to need an array at all. Just illustrating how you'd do what you're asking about using an array.  I think if I were doing something like this, I'd be thinking more about creating the `EditText`'s more programmatically.

---

---

Here's a utility method I have that creates a dialog programmatically and has some `EditText`'s in it, hope this helps.

```
public static void testNotification(final Activity activity)
{
  Dialog dlg = new Dialog(activity);
  dlg.setTitle("Notification Test");

  LinearLayout dlgView = new LinearLayout(activity);
  dlgView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  dlg.addContentView(dlgView, new LayoutParams(200, 200));

  final EditText et1 = new EditText(activity);
  et1.setText("ABC");
  dlgView.addView(et1);

  final EditText et2 = new EditText(activity);
  et2.setText("XYZ");
  dlgView.addView(et2);

  Button btn = new Button(activity);
  btn.setText("Go");
  dlgView.addView(btn);

  et1.setWidth(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
  et2.setWidth(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
  btn.setWidth(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      Util.doNotification(activity, et1.getText().toString(), et2.getText()
          .toString());
    }
  });
  dlg.show();
  return;
}
```

Comment: Cound you please give some idea of creating those textbox dynamically?

Comment: sure, I've added a utility method of mine that creates its own `EditText`'s programmatically

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not correct.You can do it this way

```
et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
et1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
et2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
et3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
et3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
et4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
et4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
et5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
et5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
  String editTextName = editText+(i+1);
  int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(editTextName , "id", getPackageName());
  EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(resID);
  et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```